# JavaScript Increase percentage of div as viewport size shrinks and decrease it as it grows, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

having a percentage relative to the size of the view port is very simple an easy but my scenario is the opposite.

just to throw a number here I'd like a div to be 100% in size if the viewport is 480px but when the viewport increases in size I'd like the width of the div to shrink. let's say once the viewport is around 1024px the div's width should be 50%;

I'm guessing the only solution would be with JavaScript. I've been scratching my head for days and I can't seem to find a way of how to do this. Can anybody help?

Comment: please provide your html structure and show us what youve tested so far

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve this with css media queries if you don't need to have it continuously change.

For example:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  div {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  div {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

This code makes div has width 100% for viewports equals or smaller than 480px and give it 50% for sizes 481-1024. You can tweak it on your own.

Comment: That's how I'm approaching this issue at the moment, with several media queries. I have about 10 media queries adjusting the width and the absolute positioning of this div which overlaps the navigation right before the mobile nav kicks in. I was looking for another more elegant solution.

Comment: I wanted to apply a more dynamic approach something like max-width: 1024 > 50%, 1014 > 51%, 1000 > 52%.....so increasing the percentage as it gets smaller, same for the top absolute position.

Comment: So you have to use js. You can bind event handler to resize event.

Comment: Eg with jQuery: $(window).resize(function(){ $(div).css('width',function(){return $(this).width()-$(window).width()/100 }) });